# Stepping into NSMakeRange every time I push the step over button where the debugging line has a call to NSMakeRange

Tags: ios, xcode, step-into

When I am debugging my app it **steps into** NSMakeRange every time I push the **step over** button where the debugging line has a call to NSMakeRange. Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `NSMakeRange` is an inline function, which means it isn't a real function, the compiler copies its code wherever you use it (a bit like a macro), so its code is actually part of your code.